# SmartGWT - How to have editable and non-editable text together in the same text area?

Tags: textbox, smartgwt

Please let me know how to approach this problem, I am naive to smartGWT.

The requirement is that:

1. I have to display a text area which has some pre-populated text.
2. Part of this pre-populated text should be editable and the part of this pre-populated text should be non-editable.
3. The editable text should be rendered in black color while the non-editable text should be rendered in gray color.

I am currently using com.smartgwt.client.widgets.form.fields.TextAreaItem class but I am open to change my class if this usecase is supported by some other widget.

**Details**:

Suppose the below lines displays the upper and lower boundary of my text area.

---

[Editable text] (This text should be editable and should have black color)

[Non editable text] (This text should be non editable and should have gray color)

[Editable text] (This text should be editable and should have black color)

---

Answer (score 0):

The TextAreaItem is rendered as a HTML textArea so just good for input not for formatting .
Perhaps you could use the RichTextItem which allow to format a text with different font and attribute.
But it is no quite sure you can customize it (to remove the tool for example) and just play with the events.
I don't think it will be so easy 
Do you have a random number of line?
If not you can design your own with a canvasItem including editable element (TextItem), non editable elements (could be TextItem with setDisabled(true) but watch the style)and assign css for the style